# Set theory question equinumerous sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]

From http://users.metu.edu.tr/serge/courses/111-2011/textbook-math111.pdf page 313
I need help with part (b).  I can 'see' what is going on, but I can't seem to produce a simple and rigorous proof.

Answer (score 0):

This can be shown by induction.Certainly, $f(1)\geq 1$, since $f(1) \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Further, assuming $f(n)\geq n$, we have that $f(n+1) > f(n) \geq n$. Since $f(n+1) > n$, we have $f(n+1) \geq n+1$. The result follows by induction.

Comment: f(n+1) > f(n) would you need to explain this?  What would you say to make it clear why this is true.

Comment: If $f(n+1) < f(n)$ then $f(n)$ would not have been the smallest number which is not of the form $f(m)$ where $m<n$. And $f(n+1)\neq f(n)$, because $f(n)\notin B\backslash \{f(m) \, \vert \, m < n+1\}$.